# Why is my system waiting for google-analytics?

Tags: browser, javascript, google-analytics

When I go to certain websites that have google analytics, they never load up.  One example is www.jquery.com.

I tried in firefox, chrome, safari and explorer.

Chrome & safari, flash the home page then it disappears and the screen goes white.

Firefox never loads anything and the spinner just keeps spinning.

Loads fine in explorer.

Any ideas of what may be going on?  If I use my laptop, on my same home internet connection, it works fine.

This is not happening on all sites with analytics, just certain ones.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your DNS settings may be messed up.

Try doing an nslookup for Google analytics.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>nslookup google-analytics.com
Server:  93.188.162.13.static.ukrtelegroup.com.ua
Address:  93.188.162.13

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google-analytics.com
Address:  66.249.91.104


C:\Windows\System32>

Comment: does this ukrtelegroup.com.ua look valid, doesn't to me.  looks like a virus or something

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DNS settings have been compromised.  Check your network settings and make sure there is nothing odd in there, you'll probably want to make sure it's set to grab your servers from DHCP.  Also be sure to check your router since it could be the device handing out the rogue DNS settings.  Also try a full malware scan since your computer may also be infected.