# Mozilla Firefox 3.5.13: Certain Websites do not load!

Tags: browser, website, firefox, google-analytics

Mozilla Firefox 3.5.13: When I try to load certain websites, it flashes the page quickly, and, at the bottom, it says:

> "Transferring data from
>   www.google-analytics.com"

Is this a virus? Or is there a setting on Firefox that I accidentally turned on?

Comment: This question should be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: I've had this problem since relocating to a foreign country, hence changing IPs. I use Chrome and am mostly OK since switching. My wife and stepdaughter still get it often on their browsers of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I remember once having this exact problem which appeared to be caused by the Adblock plugin (or to be more precise, the problem was eliminated by disabling that plugin and I took no further action).

If you don't have that plugin or it is not the cause in this case the first thing I'd try is disabling Javascript to see if it is a JS related issue. This can be done from the firefox options menu.

Comment: What he's talking about, as far as I know, is a much more systemic problem. See this question: http://superuser.com/questions/125382/why-is-my-system-waiting-for-google-analytics